# Python client for dYdX (v3 API) fails at source_client.eth.transfer_token with ERC20: transfer amount exceeds balance

Tags: python

I'm trying to do initial account funding using dydx-v3-python client.

Stuck with the following snippet from integration_tests/test_integration.py:

```
source_client = Client(eth_private_key=source_private_key_with_enough_balance ...)

# Fund the new user with ETH and USDC.
fund_eth_hash = source_client.eth.transfer_eth(
    to_address=ethereum_address,
    human_amount=0.001,
)
fund_usdc_hash = source_client.eth.transfer_token(
    to_address=ethereum_address,
    human_amount=2,
)
print('Waiting for funds...')
source_client.eth.wait_for_tx(fund_eth_hash)
source_client.eth.wait_for_tx(fund_usdc_hash)
print('...done.')
```

First transaction succeeds, and the second (transfer_token) always fails with error:

> Fail with error 'ERC20: transfer amount exceeds balance'

Source ethereum address definitely has enough balance, and I tried to play with both amounts, but the second transaction always fails

Please advise what I'm doing incorrectly, or maybe there is an issue with the code, since `test_integration.py` was last updated more than 2 years ago

Thank you